# Creating a Mapboxmap with SvelteKit results in 500 Internal Error

Tags: javascript, mapbox, svelte

I a trying to render a basic map with mapbox and svelte kit. The mapbox-code comes directly from this example here: https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/choropleth-studio-gl-pt-2/

I want to simply create this map in the `src/lib/mapboxmap.svelte`-compontent, import it into the `+page`-route and render it. Yet I am always getting a 500 internal error.

I think I'm simply misunderstanding something. Probably of how svelte kit works. This is the minimal `mapboxmap.svelte`component:

```
<script>
    import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
    import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';

    // define access token
    mapboxgl.accessToken =
        'pk.eyJ1Ijoicm9iaW5rb2hycyIsImEiOiJjanU5am95bm4xZnZ6NDNrOTRyYTYwdzJzIn0.iMFQgQIlhz36wB3819Xftw';

    // create map
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map', // container id
        style: 'mapbox://styles/examples/cjgioozof002u2sr5k7t14dim' // map style URL from Mapbox Studio
    });

    console.log('map: ', map);
</script>
```

I am then importing it into he `src/routes/+page.svelte` route like this:

```
<script>
    import Mapboxmap from '../lib/mapboxmap.svelte';
</script>

<Mapboxmap />
```

And this is the result:

[image]

I think it might be a silly question, but I can't find the solution right now

Comment: It looks like you posted your mapbox access token, you should immediately invalidate it.

Comment: that's not mine. It's from the example on the mapbox site:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the mapbox initialization part within an onMount block.
Otherwise, this code is run server-side and mapbox server won't like it, plus DOM being not initialized, the container 'map' does not exist yet (not to mention you actually have to insert it in your HTML block).
Something of the like will work :

```
<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'
    import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
    import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css';
    let map;

    onMount(async()=>{
        mapboxgl.accessToken =
        'pk.eyJ1Ijoicm9iaW5rb2hycyIsImEiOiJjanU5am95bm4xZnZ6NDNrOTRyYTYwdzJzIn0.iMFQgQIlhz36wB3819Xftw';

        // create map
        map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map', // container id
            style: 'mapbox://styles/examples/cjgioozof002u2sr5k7t14dim' // map style URL from Mapbox Studio
        });
    })
</script>
<div id="map">
```